# Prolog: Appending to a list while reusing the same list(out of local stack error)

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate that takes a list, for example:

```
[car(blue,2000), car(blue,1000), car(red,2000), car(red,3000)]
```

And two criteria , example I need to pick the first `blue` car, and from the remaining list, the first car that cost `2000`. I need to return a list of the selected car, which should be

`[car(blue,2000),car(red,2000)]`

The predicate that I have returns a `out of local stack` error. From `trace` , it seems to say that is because I'm doing `append(_8757416, [car(blue,2000)], _8757416)` , which I'm not really doing. I thought the two `append` with a temporary list would avoid this kind of bug. Here is the code, hope it can help to understand better want I'm talking about.

```
checkCriteria([],_,_).
checkCriteria(_,[],_).
checkCriteria([Criteria|T],Cars, ChosenCar):-
include(
    goal([Criteria]),
    Cars,
    FilteredList),
[H|_] = FilteredList,
append([], ChosenCar, Temp ),
append(Temp, [H], ChosenCar),
delete(H, FilteredList, NewList),
checkCriteria(T,NewList, ChosenCar).

% this predicate deletes an element from a list
delete(Y, [Y], []).
delete(X, [X|L1], L1).
delete(X, [Y|L], [Y|L1]):-delete(X,L,L1).

% this predicate check if a element respect a criteria
goal([],_). 
goal([Criteria|Cs],Element) :-
 criteria(Criteria,Element),
 goal(Cs,Element).

:- dynamic criteria/2.
criteria(blue,(car(Color, _))) :- Color = blue, car(Color, _). 
criteria(price,(car(_, Price))) :- Price = 2000, car(_,Price).

:- dynamic car/2.
car(blue,2000). 
car(blue,1000).
car(red,2000).
car(red,3000).
```

How to avoid the `out of local stack` error?

Here is the command that cause the error :

`?- checkCriteria([blue, price], [car(blue,2000), car(blue,1000), car(red,2000), car(red,3000)], X).`

Comment: Which exact goal does cause this problem for you?

Comment: Both goals cause the problem, here are the goals :


criteria(blue,(car(Color, _))) :- Color = blue, car(Color, _).
criterial(price,(car(_, Price))) :- Price = 2000, car(_,Price).

Comment: These are rules. But which is the query (= the goal) that causes the problem. What did you type in to get the error?

Comment: checkCriteria([blue, price], [car(blue,2000), car(blue,1000), car(red,2000), car(red,3000)], X).

Comment: Where is criteria/2 defined? Please edit your question accordingly

Comment: I just added the definition for criteria/2, and you can test it works with the query: include(goal([blue]), [car(blue,2000), car(blue,1000), car(red,2000), car(red,3000)], X). . Hope it helps.

Comment: Now car/2 is lacking ... Please make a complete, reproducible example

Comment: Ok, I made the modification. If you take the program as I posted it, it should compile without errors and you should be able to test the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a try and found a few issues, which I (mostly) fixed below. It works with the example, maybe it helps:

- The list `ChosenCar` was never instantiated and hence the appending to it failed. I added an extra parameter to `checkCriteria` as an accumulator list to collect the results. This is assigned to `ChosenCar` in the recursion anchors.
- You deleted the car that met the criteria from the `FilteredList` for the next recusion step, but it should be deleted from `Cars`, so that the next criteria could be checked with the remaining cars.
- Your `delete` predicate can not handle empty lists, and also `checkCriteria` assumes every criteria to be met by one of the remaining cars. You may want to look into that as well: Handle empty lists in `delete` and also the case where `FilteredList` is empty after the `include`.

```
checkCriteria([],_,ACC,ACC).
checkCriteria(_,[],ACC,ACC).
checkCriteria([Criteria|T],Cars, ACC, ChosenCar):- 
    include(
        goal([Criteria]),
        Cars,
        FilteredList),
    [H|_] = FilteredList, 
    append(ACC, [H], ACC1),
    delete(H, Cars, NewList),
    checkCriteria(T,NewList, ACC1, ChosenCar).

% this predicate deletes an element from a list
delete(Y, [Y], []).
delete(X, [X|L1], L1).
delete(X, [Y|L], [Y|L1]):-delete(X,L,L1).

% this predicate check if a element respect a criteria
goal([],_). 
goal([Criteria|Cs],Element) :- criteria(Criteria,Element), goal(Cs,Element).

:- dynamic criteria/2.
criteria(blue,car(Color, _)) :- Color = blue, car(Color, _). 
criteria(price,car(_, Price)) :- Price = 2000, car(_,Price).

:- dynamic car/2.
car(blue,2000). 
car(blue,1000).
car(red,2000).
car(red,3000).
```